# Django - Problem adding a queryset to a field on a FilterSet

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I have some filtersSets working fine, but now I tried to add a queryset to a field on the FilterSet and it fails when I load the page.

I'm using Django 2.1.1 with Python 3.6 and Django-filter 2.0.0.

## view

```
def search_jobs(request):
    job_list = Job.objects.filter(project__status="P", is_deleted="False")
    job_filter = JobsListFilter(request.GET, queryset=job_list)
    return render(request, 'webplatform/jobs_list_filter.html', {'filter': job_filter})
```

## filter

```
class JobsListFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    # LINE ADDED - the following line is the added queryset 
    projects = Project.objects.filter(status="P", is_deleted="False") 

    skills = WorkerSkills.objects.filter(
        id__in=Job.objects.values_list('required_skills__id', flat=True).distinct())

    worker_job = django_filters.CharFilter(method='my_filter')
    required_skills = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(queryset=skills, widget=forms.SelectMultiple)

    # LINE ADDED - The following line is the one that adds the queryset inside the field I want to filter.
    project = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(queryset=projects)

    compensation_type = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=Job.COMPENSATION_TYPE, widget=forms.RadioSelect)

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ['worker_job', 'required_skills', 'project', 'compensation_type']

    def my_filter(self, queryset, worker_job, value):
        return queryset.filter(
            worker_job__icontains=value
        ) | queryset.filter(
            work_description__icontains=value
        )
```

The code is working without the added lines `LINE ADDED` on the FilterSet. But the thing is that on the field `project` it just let me select between all the projects created, and I want to have only the ones that are really necessary (applying the queriset on the code).

But adding those lines in the code, when I use debug mode I can see the queryset applied on the field `project` giving the expected results. But then, on the `return` of the view is throwing the following error.

`TypeError at /platform/search/jobs/
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queryset'`

So I don't know what I did wrong, because I'm using the same structure used on the required_skills field adding a queryset with only the objects that I want and it should work.

Comment: I think you've just selected the wrong class for the project filter field, you probably meant to use a `django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter` which is the one accepting a queryset as an argument https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html?highlight=choicefilter#modelchoicefilter

Comment: you are completely right, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Moisés Hiraldo said on the comments, the problem is that I had to use `django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter` in front of `django_filters.ChoiceFilter`.